# Rails Form Not Writing to Database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having an issue writing information from a newly added column to my mysql database. Specifically 'site_email'. When I run the project locally I *can* write to the database with my newly column content and it appears on the subsequent show page.

However on the dev server I cannot. The development server logs show the content being sent in the request.

```
Started PUT "/sites/18" for x.x.139.147 at 2012-12-03 19:47:39 +0000
      Processing by SitesController#update as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6QXzdALrXqXoQz+Q5SFXd+egNQGxOAdNIC8ZH9A9yqU=", "site"=>{"customer_id"=>"1", "site_name"=>"Demohello", "site_domain"=>"Demo", "site_email"=>"test@email.comhello", "google_analytics_code"=>"", "visible"=>"1", "mobile_visible"=>"1", "logo_cache"=>"", "background_logo_cache"=>"", "header_cache"=>"", "background_cache"=>"", "campaign_wrapbar_cache"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Site", "id"=>"18"}
    Redirected to http://x.com/sites/18
    Completed 302 Found in 17ms
```

but then when it goes to the show page the new/update email data is not there. Strangely if I add any data to pre-exisiting columns as well that other data is successfully sent to the database but the email is not.

The index show and edit pages all display without errors and if I manually change the information in the database it shows up on the show page. I am at a total loss as to even debug this as the request data is sent and the page produces no errors.

from /var/www/sitename/current I ran

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Connecting to the dev database using SequelPro I can see that the column looks to be there, and indeed if I insert a value in the site_email column the data appears on the show page.

DB

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSKDs.png

Show page with inserted value

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxbN6.png

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@site) do |f| %>
  <% if @site.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@site.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this site from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
      <% @site.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :customer_id %><br />
    <%#= f.text_field :customer %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:customer_id, Customer.all , :id , :customer_name ) %>

  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :site_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :site_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :site_domain %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :site_domain %>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :site_email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :site_email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :google_analytics_code %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :google_analytics_code %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :visible %><br />
   <%= f.check_box :visible %><br />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :mobile_visible %><br />
    <%= f.check_box :mobile_visible %><br />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :logo %>
    <%= f.file_field :logo %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :logo_cache %><br />
    <%= image_tag(@site.logo_url) if @site.logo? %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :background_logo %>
    <%= f.file_field :background_logo %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :background_logo_cache %><br />
    <%= image_tag(@site.background_logo_url) if @site.background_logo? %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :header %>
    <%= f.file_field :header %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :header_cache %><br />
    <%= image_tag(@site.header_url) if @site.header? %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :background %>
    <%= f.file_field :background %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :background_cache %><br />
    <%= image_tag(@site.background_url) if @site.background? %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :campaign_wrapbar %>
    <%= f.file_field :campaign_wrapbar %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :campaign_wrapbar_cache %><br />
    <%= image_tag(@site.campaign_wrapbar_url) if @site.campaign_wrapbar? %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

show.html.erb

```
<section id="otherpage">
  <div class="otherpagetitle"> <%= @site.site_name %></div>
  <div class="otherpagetext dark_border_24_no_pad">

    <p>
      <b>Site name:</b>
      <%= @site.site_name %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <b>Site customer:</b>
      <%= @site.customer %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <b>Site domain:</b>
      <%= @site.site_domain %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <b>Site email:</b>
      <%= @site.site_email %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <b>Google analytics code:</b>
      <%= @site.google_analytics_code %>
    </p>

    <div class="field">
      <p>
        <b>Visible: </b>
        <%= check_box_tag "Visible", "yes", @site.visible, disabled: true %>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <p>
        <b>Mobile Visible: </b>
        <%= check_box_tag "Mobile Visible", "yes", @site.mobile_visible, disabled: true %>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <p>
        <b>Logo: </b><br />
        <%= @site.logo? ? image_tag(@site.logo_url) : "No logo uploaded" %>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <p>
        <b>Background Logo: </b><br />
        <%= @site.background_logo? ? image_tag(@site.background_logo_url) : "No background logo uploaded" %>
      </p>
    </div>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_site_path(@site) %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', sites_path %>
  </div>
</section>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<section id="otherpage">

      <div class="otherpagetitle">Editing Site</div>
      <div class="otherpagetext dark_border_24_no_pad">


        <%= render 'form' %>

        <%= link_to 'Show', @site %> |
        <%= link_to 'Back', sites_path %>
      </div>
    </section>
```

sites_controller.rb

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource


  # GET /sites
  # GET /sites.json
  def index
    @sites = Site.all
    @site = Site.first(conditions: { site_domain: request.subdomain }) || not_found

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @sites }
    end
  end

  # GET /sites/1
  # GET /sites/1.json
  def show
    @site = Site.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @site }
    end
  end

  # GET /sites/new
  # GET /sites/new.json
  def new
    @site = Site.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @site }
    end
  end

  # GET /sites/1/edit
  def edit
    @site = Site.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /sites
  # POST /sites.json
  def create
    @site = Site.new(params[:site])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @site.save
        format.html { redirect_to @site, notice: 'Site was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @site, status: :created, location: @site }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @site.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /sites/1
  # PUT /sites/1.json
  def update
    @site = Site.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @site.update_attributes(params[:site])
        format.html { redirect_to @site, notice: 'Site was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @site.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /sites/1
  # DELETE /sites/1.json
  def destroy
    @site = Site.find(params[:id])
    @site.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to sites_url }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end

  def site_styles
    @site = Site.first(conditions: { site_domain: request.subdomain }) || not_found

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @site }
      format.css
    end
  end
end
```

Gemlock.file

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.1.5)
      actionpack (= 3.1.5)
      mail (~> 2.3.3)
    actionpack (3.1.5)
      activemodel (= 3.1.5)
      activesupport (= 3.1.5)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.6)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.4)
    activemodel (3.1.5)
      activesupport (= 3.1.5)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.5)
      activemodel (= 3.1.5)
      activesupport (= 3.1.5)
      arel (~> 2.2.3)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.1.5)
      activemodel (= 3.1.5)
      activesupport (= 3.1.5)
    activesupport (3.1.5)
      multi_json (>= 1.0, < 1.3)
    ansi (1.4.2)
    arel (2.2.3)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    best_in_place (1.0.6)
      jquery-rails
      rails (~> 3.1)
    builder (3.0.0)
    cancan (1.6.7)
    capistrano (2.11.2)
      highline
      net-scp (>= 1.0.0)
      net-sftp (>= 2.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.14)
      net-ssh-gateway (>= 1.1.0)
    capistrano-ext (1.2.1)
      capistrano (>= 1.0.0)
    carrierwave (0.5.8)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
    ckeditor (3.7.0.rc2)
      mime-types (~> 1.17.2)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.0.6)
    coffee-rails (3.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
    daemons (1.1.8)
    devise (1.5.3)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.0.3)
      warden (~> 1.1)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (0.12.10)
    execjs (1.2.13)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    friendly_id (4.0.1)
    has_scope (0.5.1)
    highline (1.6.11)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    inherited_resources (1.2.2)
      has_scope (~> 0.5.0)
      responders (~> 0.6.0)
    jquery-rails (1.0.19)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.7.3)
    mail (2.3.3)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.17.2)
    mini_magick (3.4)
      subexec (~> 0.2.1)
    minitest (2.6.1)
    multi_json (1.2.0)
    mysql2 (0.3.11)
    net-scp (1.0.4)
      net-ssh (>= 1.99.1)
    net-sftp (2.0.5)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.9)
    net-ssh (2.3.0)
    net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
      net-ssh (>= 1.99.1)
    orm_adapter (0.0.6)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.3.6)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.5)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.5)
      actionpack (= 3.1.5)
      activerecord (= 3.1.5)
      activeresource (= 3.1.5)
      activesupport (= 3.1.5)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.5)
    rails-i18n (0.3.0)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    railties (3.1.5)
      actionpack (= 3.1.5)
      activesupport (= 3.1.5)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    responders (0.6.5)
    sass (3.1.15)
    sass-rails (3.1.4)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.4)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.0)
      tilt (~> 1.3.2)
    sprockets (2.0.4)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.5)
    subexec (0.2.1)
    thin (1.3.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    truncate_html (0.5.4)
    turn (0.8.3)
      ansi
    tzinfo (0.3.33)
    uglifier (1.2.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    will_paginate (3.0.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  best_in_place
  cancan
  capistrano-ext
  carrierwave
  ckeditor (= 3.7.0.rc2)
  coffee-rails (~> 3.1.1)
  devise (~> 1.5)
  execjs (~> 1.2.11)
  friendly_id
  inherited_resources
  jquery-rails
  mini_magick
  minitest
  mysql2 (~> 0.3.11)
  rails (~> 3.1.4)
  rails-i18n
  sass-rails (= 3.1.4)
  sqlite3
  thin
  truncate_html
  turn
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  will_paginate (~> 3.0)
```

migration

```
class AddSiteEmailColumnToSites < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        add_column :sites, :site_email, :string
      end
    end
```

capistrano deploy

```
cap staging deploy
    triggering load callbacks
  * 2012-12-03 20:45:57 executing `staging'
    triggering start callbacks for `deploy'
  * 2012-12-03 20:45:57 executing `multistage:ensure'
Identity added: /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa)
  * 2012-12-03 20:45:57 executing `deploy'
  * 2012-12-03 20:45:57 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2012-12-03 20:45:57 executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "git ls-remote ssh://gitolite@site_repo:2011/proto_mysitename_rails HEAD"
    command finished in 2997ms
  * executing "git clone -q ssh://gitolite@site_repo:2011/proto_mysitename_rails /var/www/sitename/releases/20121203204600 && cd /var/www/sitename/releases/20121203204600 && git checkout -q -b deploy ed9ca3a2f10b049ed17b952d90ec7b61e9e98822 && (echo ed9ca3a2f10b049ed17b952d90ec7b61e9e98822 > /var/www/sitename/releases/20121203204600/REVISION)"
    servers: ["x.x.x.x"]
    [x.x.x.x] executing command
    command finished in 80618ms
  * 2012-12-03 20:47:21 executing `deploy:finalize_update'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * 2012-12-03 20:47:21 executing `deploy:assets:symlink'
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/sitename/releases/20121203204600/public/assets &&\\\n        mkdir -p /var/www/sitename/releases/20121203204600/public &&\\\n        mkdir -p /var/www/sitename/shared/assets &&\\\n        ln -s /var/www/sitename/shared/assets /var/www/sitename/releases/20121203204600/public/assets"
    servers: ["x.x.x.x"]
    [x.x.x.x] executing command
    command finished in 118ms
  * executing "chmod -R -- g+w /var/www/sitename/releases/20121203204600 && rm -rf -- /var/www/sitename/releases/20121203204600/public/system && mkdir -p -- /var/www/sitename/releases/20121203204600/public/ && ln -s -- /var/www/sitename/shared/system /var/www/sitename/releases/20121203204600/public/system && rm -rf -- /var/www/sitename/releases/20121203204600/log && ln -s -- /var/www/sitename/shared/log /var/www/sitename/releases/20121203204600/log && rm -rf -- /var/www/sitename/releases/20121203204600/tmp/pids && mkdir -p -- /var/www/sitename/releases/20121203204600/tmp/ && ln -s -- /var/www/sitename/shared/pids /var/www/sitename/releases/20121203204600/tmp/pids"
    servers: ["x.x.x.x"]
    [x.x.x.x] executing command
    command finished in 120ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
  * 2012-12-03 20:47:21 executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * executing "cd /var/www/sitename/releases/20121203204600 && rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
    servers: ["x.x.x.x"]
    [x.x.x.x] executing command
 ** [out :: x.x.x.x] /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/rake assets:precompile:nondigest RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
    command finished in 101748ms
  * 2012-12-03 20:49:03 executing `deploy:create_symlink'
  * executing "rm -f /var/www/sitename/current && ln -s /var/www/sitename/releases/20121203204600 /var/www/sitename/current"
    servers: ["x.x.x.x"]
    [x.x.x.x] executing command
    command finished in 111ms
 ** transaction: commit
  * 2012-12-03 20:49:03 executing `deploy:restart'
  * executing "rm /var/www/sitename/current/config/database.yml"
    servers: ["x.x.x.x"]
    [x.x.x.x] executing command
    command finished in 65ms
  * executing "ln -s /var/www/sitename/shared/database.yml /var/www/sitename/current/config/database.yml"
    servers: ["x.x.x.x"]
    [x.x.x.x] executing command
    command finished in 65ms
  * executing "ln -s /var/www/sitename/shared/session_store.rb /var/www/sitename/current/config/initializers/session_store.rb"
    servers: ["x.x.x.x"]
    [x.x.x.x] executing command
    command finished in 69ms
  * executing "ln -s /var/www/sitename/shared/public/uploads /var/www/sitename/current/public/uploads"
    servers: ["x.x.x.x"]
    [x.x.x.x] executing command
    command finished in 63ms
  * executing "ln -s /var/www/sitename/shared/public/ckeditor_assets /var/www/sitename/current/public/ckeditor_assets"
    servers: ["x.x.x.x"]
    [x.x.x.x] executing command
    command finished in 62ms
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' touch /var/www/sitename/current/tmp/restart.txt"
    servers: ["x.x.x.x"]
    [x.x.x.x] executing command
```

Any help or advice on this issue is more than welcome.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

Without changing a thing the values now write to the database. 24 or so later. I am now having the same issue with the live server. I am waiting another 24 hours to see if that sorts the issue or if I accidentally fixed it in some other way.

Just in case someone else has this issue in future, does anyone have an idea why it might behave in this way?

**Update 2**

Live server now updating the values as well. It seems to be that the server might be under heavy load or that the database is playing up in some way.

**Reference**

For reference if you try try all the suggestions in the comments and also look at Thomas' answer this should fix the issue in 99.9% of all cases. If it is working locally but not on the server AND the you've tried all these steps, it could well be the same issue as I was having and unfortunately I have no real answer for this at present.

Comment: please show your controller code..

Comment: did you migrate your database?

Comment: added. thanks for the spot. @samullen I've added the rake command I ran

Comment: Okay, one more step back: You're talking about running local and on some development server. How do you deploy? You'll need to run your migrations on the remote server.

Comment: I deploy using capistrano and I ran `bundle exec rake db:migrate` from the /current directory on the server

Comment: Did you try `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`?

Comment: @niiru yeah I tried that as well. When i first ran bundle exec rake db:migrate on the dev server it did create the new column. I will add a screenshot of a section of the db from sequelpro.

Comment: Longshot: In your logs the email was "test@email.comhello". Do you have validations which would catch erroneous email address?

Comment: @samullen It rejects all email addresses including gmail and hotmail. I didn't implement this part of the project but have had to take it over. I have now added the migration and also the gemlock.file..

Comment: do you have attr_accessible on your Site model?

Comment: @JohnNaegle attr_accessible is not in my site.rb file. What is strange is that this runs locally just fine

Answer (score 2):

This could be some kind of mass-assignment issue, where attributes are silently dropped if they are not listed unless certain settings have been made.

Try adding `:site_email`to your call to `attr_accessible`in your site model.

```
# app/models/site.rb
...
attr_accessible :name, :site_email # mass-assignment protection
```

You need to list all attributes there that you want to be able to update through `@site.update_attributes(params[:site]`in your controller and instantiate with the so called **mass-assignment** with `Site.new(name: ..., site_email: ...)` or `Site.create(name: ..., site_email: ...)`.

Comment: Eventually the database entries started to be entered in the database (about 24 hours later) and they now update straight away. Any ideas why there is a delay before the functionality kicks in?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why there could be a delay of 24 hours. It usually should update right away and only take a few seconds when the database is under moderate load. Might be a quirk of your specific setup.

Comment: Also, if you assign `attr_accessible` in your model but do not checkin the model with git and push to production you won't be able to save the record.  I had the same problem this morning while adding columns to my app half asleep.